# Adding User Libraries in another user libraries in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jar, libraries

GIVEN:
I have one User library as "PrimaryLib" which contains 9 jars, then I created "SecondaryLib" user library which contains 3 jars.
My Question:
Now I want to add PrimaryLib in SecondaryLib so that my SecondaryLib user library will have total 12 jars(I don't want to select those 9 jars again, I want to just select PrimaryLib user library), How to do that?

Comment: No need to add jar into jar . Add both jars to classpath - set classpath order to define what comes after.

Comment: I think better use some of build system, like maven, gradle

Comment: I am using maven from 2 months(nearly), but this question is still in my brain and I thought it will be cool to add userLibrary into userLibrary hehe @Ivan

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if "libraries" is the "answer" to your situation.

You could control that using project exports - you have a central project that uses both libraries; and you define its export to show all 12 JARs.

Then other users just "include" that project, and they are happy to go. And when you add another library, or want to change the exported JARs ... you just change your project setup.

In other words: for eclipse, quote *A user library is a set of JAR files*.
Meaning: a library contains JARs - not other libraries.

If you want to "provide" a certain set of JARs, that should be "accessible" together, than the easiest way to get there is to

1. Create a new project; and in the "Build path settings" of that new project:
2. Add those libraries to the project that you are interested in
3. Select those JARs on the "order and export" page

And now, you can use that add that new project as dependency to all those projects that are need for those JARs.

Comment: I updated my answer to give that what I think the "eclipse" POV is.